# How to take input value to the button to pass as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, angular

Here is my code in html. I want to parse the parameter called `area`(string) to `searchTeacher` function:

```
<input  type="text" placeholder="Search Teachers by Area" aria-label="Search"/>  
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light" (click)="searchTeacher(area)" (click)="hideMainList()"></button>
```

Comment: Hi, there is not code in your post, please edit and add it.

Comment: @UltraSL you forgot to add the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables).

Your code would then look like this:

```
<input #area type="text" placeholder="Search Teachers by Area" aria-label="Search"/>  
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light" (click)="searchTeacher(area.value)" (click)="hideMainList()">Search</button>
```